# How to make Android application use Iptables without root privileges

Tags: android, iptables, netfilter

I don't have much experience in the Android framework.
I need to develop Android API or something to make the application use Iptables without root privilege(without rooting device).

I have no idea how to start and how to design it.
Do I have to implement a kernel module which accesses Netfilter and expose API to the user?

Could you help me how to do it or how to start it?
If you have any idea about how to implement it Please help me...